# Can I use Ruby and Python together?

Tags: python, ruby

Is there something like JRuby but for Ruby and Python?
Not that it would actually be useful to me, but just wondering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you develop for the .NET Framework Version 4.0, you can write code in IronRuby that calls methods that were written in IronPython and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

[Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

Comment: Thanks,this is great. I assume Jython and JRuby play nice?

Answer (score 1):

[Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/) aims. Not quite sure about its progress, though.

Answer (score 0):

_why was working on something called [unholy](http://github.com/whymirror/unholy), which converted ruby to Python bytecode.